# R Plotly - Mapping Colors to a Variable

Tags: r, plotly

I am creating a map in plotly (using mapbox), and I am trying to match colors to a variable. I have been able to differentiate them without issue, but I can't choose which colors I want to use. Here is the map and the code I have tried:

[image]

[image]

```
colorslist <- c("blue", "green", "orange", "red")
priceplot3 <- listings2 %>% 
  plot_mapbox() %>% 
  add_markers(
    x = ~avelong,
    y = ~avelat,
    size = 10,
    color = ~logaveprice,
    text = ~paste0(neighbourhood, ", Average Price: $", round(aveprice, 2)),
    hoverinfo = "text",
    name = "AirBnBs"
  ) %>% 
  add_sf(data = stations2, name = "Stations", hoverinfo = ~name, size = 5) %>% 
  add_sf(data = tracks2, color = ~name, colors = colorslist, hoverinfo = ~name, size = 1, opacity = 0.5) %>% 
  add_sf(data = bostonnbh, color = I("darkgray"), fill = NA, name = "Neighborhoods", hoverinfo = "text") %>% 
  layout(mapbox = 
           list(
             center = list(lon = -71.06, lat = 42.3), 
             zoom = 10,
             style = "dark"
             ))
priceplot3
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do. I've also tried putting an I() for each color in the list. From what I've been able to find, this should be the way to do it, but it's not working.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

I apologize that this isn't reproducible. I can edit it to make it easier to reproduce, or I can send anyone the data and the full code, if it would help.

Thank you!